TensorFlow, Keras & image preprocessing
I want to add a preprocessing layer to my model as suggested by Aurélien Géron in his book.
I found this function:
def decode_and_resize(img_path):
    img = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, IMAGE_SIZE)
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    return img

for tf.data.Dataset.map. So I tried to adapt it for my needs:
def load_image(path):
    # 1. Read image
    img = tf.io.read_file(path)
    # 2. Decode and convert to RGB
    img = tf.image.decode_image(img, channels=3)
    # 3. Resize to the desired size
    img = keras.preprocessing.image.smart_resize(img, (224, 224))
    # 4. Convert to float32 in [0, 1] range
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    return img

Finally, I passed it to keras.layers.Lambda:
encoder_inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)
keras.layers.Lambda(load_image, dtype=tf.string)(encoder_inputs)

Unfortunately tf.io.read_file fails and the following exception (InvalidArgumentError) is thrown:
Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for '{{node ReadFile}} = ReadFile[](Placeholder)' with input shapes: [?].

from here.
I'm still learning Keras and TensorFlow, so I'm not sure if my code makes sense. For this reason I decided to open this question.
Thanks in advance!

Try this:
def load_image_batch(paths):
imgs = tf.map_fn(load_image, paths, fn_output_signature=tf.float32)
return imgs
encoder_inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)
x = keras.layers.Lambda(load_image_batch, output_shape=(224, 224, 3))(encoder_inputs)
